# Why my columns dissapear? How to reorder columns in code in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have very  strange problem in Visual Studio. I created grid on my windows form with 10 columns.

[image]

Everything works fine until I reordered the columns - all columns disappear!

[image]

[image]

I click undo, it gives back to me only 6 columns.

[image]

When I want to add 4 columns that are missing, the program throw error: This column already exist(or something like that). Then I have to get the latest version (I checked in before) to get all columns back. When I change anything in grid, same error happens every time. I tried to delete grid and make new one - same error. I even tried to delete WF and make new one - same error.

Any idea why is this happening?

Any idea how to reorder columns in code and bypass this strange error?

Comment: corrupt designer file?

Comment: Have you tried running the program to see how it looks? As Viru says it could be something wrong with the designer file.

Comment: I don't know... I already said that I delete grid and even WF and create it again and same thing happened. There are so many WF in this solution and every single class is working just fine... Ciara, when I run program there is no columns in this form, or only 6 of 10(depends if i click undo or not). Is it possible to reorder columns in code?

Comment: Is it a standard `DataGridView` control or is it the one called `popupGrid` which would suggest it's a custom control?

Comment: In Menus & Toolbars you have ContextMenuStrip - that is popupGrid.

Comment: If you really create new one form with new one grid, there cannot be same error, unless you copy something from old form. This obviously a designer file problem.

Comment: Open YourForm.Designer.cs file and check where is the name of column which raises a error - try to modify or delete it there

Comment: Fabio, I copied some code from old form. The only thing in my code that is different with code in other WF is that I have two constructors in this one. I have tried to modify code in designer, no luck with that...

Comment: You should never be modifying the designer code yourself, that's exactly what causes these types of issue.

Comment: Equalsk, I know, I modified designer only when this error happens...

Comment: Exceptions at design-time will most certainly cause stuff to disappear.  Why you are getting an exception is impossible to guess, nobody can get a code repro from screenshots.  Start VS again and attach it to the first instance so you can debug the exception.  And read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to control the code and not the same assistant you are doing.
To do this use the following example:

```
if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn1"].HeaderText = "Text 1";
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn1"].Width = 60;
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn1"].Index = 0;

    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn2"].HeaderText = "Text 2";
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn2"].Width = 60;
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn2"].Index = 1;

    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn3"].HeaderText = "Text 3";
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn3"].Width = 60;
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn3"].Index = 2;

    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn4"].Visible= false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn5"].Visible= false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["idColumn6"].Visible= false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the main problem is not resolved, but if somebody have same error, you can reorder your columns in code like this:

```
private void TransakcijaZaFakturisanje_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         gridTransakcijaZaFakturisanje.Columns["SifraTransakcije"].DisplayIndex = 0;
         gridTransakcijaZaFakturisanje.Columns["Opis"].DisplayIndex = 1;
         gridTransakcijaZaFakturisanje.Columns["SifraKomitenta"].DisplayIndex = 2;
         gridTransakcijaZaFakturisanje.Columns["IdUgovor"].DisplayIndex = 3;
         gridTransakcijaZaFakturisanje.Columns["IdUsluga"].DisplayIndex = 4;
         gridTransakcijaZaFakturisanje.Columns["VaziOd"].DisplayIndex = 5;
         gridTransakcijaZaFakturisanje.Columns["VaziDo"].DisplayIndex = 6;
         //and so on...
     }
```

I will continue to research the problem, if I find something usefull I will type it here. Thank you all for your support!